# Creating a program that compares two lists

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to create a program that checks whether items from one list are not in another. It keeps returning lines saying that x value is not in the list. Any suggestions? Sorry about my code, it's quite sloppy.

## Searching Within an Array

## Putting .txt files into arrays

```
with open('Barcodes', 'r') as f:
    barcodes = [line.strip() for line in f]

with open('EAN Staging', 'r') as f:
    EAN_staging = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

## Arrays

```
list1 = barcodes
list2 = EAN_staging
```

## Main Code

```
fixed = -1

for x in list1:
    for variable in list1:                                                  # Moves along each variable in the list, in turn
        if list1[fixed] in list2:                                           # If the term is in the list, then
            fixed = fixed + 1
            location = list2.index(list1[fixed])                            # Finds the term in the list
            print ()
            print ("Found", variable ,"at location", location)              # Prints location of terms
```

Comment: So you want to know which Items are only in one of the lists?

Comment: What is the first `for x in list1` loop for? Does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: @DeepSpace No, I want to check whether any data in the Barcodes list, is not in the EAS staging list.

Comment: @tobias_k Have removed that loop now.

Comment: @minidave2014 Ok, please see my updated answer.

Comment: `filter(lambda item, EAN_staging=EAN_staging: item not in EAN_staging, barrcodes)` filter out barcodes with items in EAN_staging.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of lists, read the files as sets:

```
with open('Barcodes', 'r') as f:
    barcodes = {line.strip() for line in f}

with open('EAN Staging', 'r') as f:
    EAN_staging = {line.strip() for line in f}
```

Then all you need to do is to calculate the symmetric difference between them:

```
diff = barcodes - EAN_staging  # or barcodes.difference(EAN_stagin)
```

An extracted example:

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {3, 4, 5}
print(a - b)
>> {1, 2, 4, 5}  # 1, 2 are in a but in b
```

Note that if you are operating with sets, information about how many times an element is present will be lost. If you care about situations when an element is present in `barcodes` 3 times, but only 2 times in `EAN_staging`, you should use `Counter` from `collections`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to quite answer your question.  If all you want to do is see which elements aren't shared, I think `set`s are the way to go.

```
set1 = set(list1)
set2 = set(list2)
in_first_but_not_in_second = set1.difference(set2)  # outputs a set
not_in_both = set1.symmetric_difference(set2)  # outputs a set
```